# using bundler to require dll with gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, bundler, require

I'm trying to build gem file that will require the dll "libmysql.dll" with the gem mysql.
Didn't find any documentation on it at http://bundler.io website and searched the internet. 
currently this is the gem file:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'json'
gem 'trollop'
gem 'activeresource', '~> 3.2.21'
gem 'activesupport',  '~> 3.2.21'
gem 'activemodel',    '~> 3.2.21'
gem 'mysql',          '~> 2.9.1'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL connector from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) which will install libmysql.dll file and then run `bundle install`.

Comment: thanks, I've done it already.
The question is how to add require to the gem file to check if "libmysql.dll" exists.